# Unicode characters with BlobStore in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

Is there a way to store unicode data with App Engine's BlobStore (in Python)?

I'm saving the data like this

```
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
     f.write('<as><a>' + '</a><a>'.join(stringInUnicode) + '</a></as>')
```

But on the production (not development) server I'm getting this error. It seems to be converting my Unicode into ASCII and I don't know why.

Why is it trying to convert back to ASCII? Can I avoid this?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/1.349473606437967000/myfile.py", line 137, in get
   f.write('<as><a>' + '</a><a>'.join(stringInUnicode) + '</a></as>')
 File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 364, in write
   self._make_rpc_call_with_retry('Append', request, response)
 File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 472, in _make_rpc_call_with_retry
   _make_call(method, request, response)
 File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 226, in _make_call
   rpc.make_call(method, request, response)
 File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 509, in make_call
   self.__rpc.MakeCall(self.__service, method, request, response)
 File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 115, in MakeCall
   self._MakeCallImpl()
 File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/apiproxy.py", line 161, in _MakeCallImpl
   self.request.Output(e)
 File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 204, in Output
   self.OutputUnchecked(e)
 File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file_service_pb.py", line 2390, in OutputUnchecked
   out.putPrefixedString(self.data_)
 File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 432, in putPrefixedString
   v = str(v)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 313: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I don't see the actual writing line, but try .encode/.decode("utf-8")

Comment: You can't 'convert back to ASCII' if you have non-ascii characters. You probably need to know what encoding the files you're loading are in. utf-8 is common, but some applications (especially on Windows) will use cp1252 or any of a range of other encodings.

Comment: @Bemmu I've added the full stack trace and the line I'm trying to write. @Thomas K I'm not trying to convert (because it obviously won't work) into ASCII I'm trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A BLOB store contains binary data: bytes, not characters. So you're going to have to do an encode step of some sort. `utf-8` seems as good an encoding as any.

```
f.write('<as><a>' + '</a><a>'.join(stringInUnicode) + '</a></as>')
```

This will go wrong if an item in `stringInUnicode` contains `<`, `&` or `]]>` sequences. You'll want to do some escaping (either using a proper XML library to serialise the data, or manually):

```
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    f.write('<as>')
    for line in stringInUnicode:
        line= line.replace(u'&', u'&amp;').replace(u'<', u'&lt;').replace(u'>', u'&gt;');
        f.write('<a>%s</a>' % line.encode('utf-8'))
    f.write('</as>')
```

(This will still be ill-formed XML if the strings ever include control characters, but there's not so much you can do about that. If you need to store arbitrary binary in XML you'd need some ad-hoc encoding such as base-64 on top.)

Comment: I believe you also need to encode double and single quotes to `&quot;` and `&apos;` respectively. Yeah the invalid control characters shouldn't matter to my parser I hope. Not using binary data, just some names in unicode. I'm going to give this a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: quot/apos would be needed in an attribute value where the corresponding quote character was being used as the delimiter, yes. Otherwise, outside of quoted attribute values, you don't need to (though it doesn't hurt). You don't always need `&gt;` either, only in the sequence `]]>`; because no-one really groks the obscure reasons why that is, though, escaping to `&gt;` all the time is kind of reasonable/consistent.